# Spring boot mysql sleep connections

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

Im building a app that with spring boot that uses mysql as db, as im seen is that spring boot opens 10 connections with the db but uses only one.

Every time i run show processlist on db, 9 connections are sleep and only one is doing something.

There's a way to split all the process between the 10 opened connections?

My app need better mysql processing because every minute about 300 records is inserted, so i think spliting between this opened connections will get better results.

My aplication.yml:

```
security:
    basic:
      enabled: false
  server:
    context-path: /invest/
    compression:
      enabled: true
      mime-types:
      - application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain
  spring:
    jackson:
      default-property-inclusion: non-null
      serialization:
        write-bigdecimal-as-plain: true
      deserialization:
        read-enums-using-to-string: true
    datasource:
      platform: MYSQL
      url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/invest?useSSL=true
      username: #
      password: #
      separator: $$
      dbcp2:
        test-while-idle: true
        validation-query: SELECT 1
    jpa:
      show-sql: false    
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: update
        naming:
          strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
      properties:
        hibernate:
          dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    http:
      encoding:
        charset: UTF-8
        enabled: true
        force: true
```

There's a way to do this?

Comment: The fact that only one connection from the pool is used suggests that in fact you don't need more.

Comment: @chrylis yes i need, as i say, i have about 300 records every minute, and growing.. So, theres a way to force it to use all the connections?

Comment: Show your code that's actually doing things. Spring will load balance automatically if you're doing independent operations.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can check my.ini,[mysqld] max_connections ,make sure more connections are allowed by your mysql.
2. You can adjust these config in your application.yml

   spring.datasource.max-active
   spring.datasource.max-age
   spring.datasource.max-idle
   spring.datasource.max-lifetime
   spring.datasource.max-open-prepared-statements
   spring.datasource.max-wait
   spring.datasource.maximum-pool-size
   spring.datasource.min-evictable-idle-time-millis
   spring.datasource.min-idle

After all, I do not think this is a problem . Mysql can handle 1000+ insertion per second. 300 per minute is too few for pool to open more than one connection.